# how C# differentiates different delegate signature?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

the `UseExtensions` has two methods

```
public static class UseExtensions {

   // method1
   public static IApplicationBuilder Use(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<HttpContext, RequestDelegate, Task> middleware) {
      ...
   }
   
   // method2
   public static IApplicationBuilder Use(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task> middleware) {
      ...
   }
}
```

so when we write:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
   await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World");
   await next();
});
```

it always calls method2, how can I rewrite the above method so that method1 is picked by the compiler?

Comment: IMO if there is a meaningful difference between the two methods then they shouldn't be named the same, in this case.

Comment: Why does it matter which implementation is picked? Are you running into a concrete issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the type of the arguments in the lambda

```
app.Use(async (HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) => ...
```

Just because we don't usually specify then doesn't mean we aren't allowed to, and specifying them in a case like this allows the compiler to make a different judgement about "which one of these two similar things  is a better match for..."